# Initialize PDF.js in website

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, cakephp-2.5, pdf.js

I am trying to integrate `PDF.js` in my website, but am unable to get it done correctly.

This is what the screen shows:

[image]

I can not see the PDF file on the screen, but when I press `Print`, the print menu does show the PDF file in it. Other functionality is working fine.

This is my code:

```
[[HTML HERE downloaded from source of PDF.JS]]

<!-- This snippet is used in production (included from viewer.html) -->
<link rel="resource" type="application/l10n" href="<?php echo JS_LIB_FOLDER; ?>pdfjs/web/locale/locale.properties"/>

<?php
echo $this->Html->css(JS_LIB_FOLDER . 'pdfjs/web/viewer.css');

echo $this->Html->script(JS_LIB_FOLDER . 'pdfjs/web/compatibility.js');
echo $this->Html->script(JS_LIB_FOLDER . 'pdfjs/web/l10n.js');
echo $this->Html->script(JS_LIB_FOLDER . 'pdfjs/build/pdf.js');
echo $this->Html->script(JS_LIB_FOLDER . 'pdfjs/web/debugger.js');
echo $this->Html->script(JS_LIB_FOLDER . 'pdfjs/web/viewer.js');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';
    PDFJS.imageResourcesPath = site_url+'js/library/pdfjs/web/images/';
    PDFJS.workerSrc = site_url+'js/library/pdfjs/build/pdf.worker.js';
    PDFJS.cMapUrl = site_url+'js/library/pdfjs/web/cmaps/';

</script>
```

I have googled this issue extensively, but found nothing on how to successfully integrate this library. Any penny help will be appreciated.

**P.S.** There is no error in javascript console.

Comment: "But unable to get it done correctly." is not a description of a problem. What **specific** issues are you running into? We're not going to go through hundreds of lines of mostly irrelevant code to try and decipher what your issue is.

Comment: please reduce the supplied code to a minimum sample reproducing the error

Comment: @Parixit You still haven't described what *does* happen. What have you done to troubleshoot? Have you tried a minimal page with PDF.js to make sure that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in your layout (e.g. `/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp`), your content block is wrapped in divs:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The PDFJS canvas will be hidden, and you won't be able to visualize the PDF.

If you check the computed layout for `<div id="outerContainer">`in Firebug, this is what you get:

[image: Computed layout for <div id="outerContainer">]

That is 1212 pixels wide, but 0 pixels tall.

You can either remove the divs wrapping your content block in your layout, or you can assign a height to the divs. E.g.:

```
<div id="outerContainer" style="height:400px">
```